# Oracle WE8ISO8859P15 charset convert to utf8 in perl script

Tags: perl, oracle, utf-8, character-encoding

At firt, I have a database where i'm not allowed to changes anything so i have to deal with the given charset.

Here is the charset of the database:

```
SELECT * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS 
 WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY', 'NLS_CHARACTERSET');

NLS_LANGUAGE             GERMAN     
NLS_TERRITORY            GERMANY
NLS_CHARACTERSET         WE8ISO8859P15
```

When doing a connection to this database (with perl) i set the connection charset to `WE8ISO8859P15`. I think i'm doing it right so far. :)

Now comes the tricky part, that fails. The data from the database needs to be converted to utf8, to look right in the browser, where i use my data.

To my understanding setting NLS_LANG should handle this to me? When setting it, it should convert the `WE8ISO8859P15` data (on the fly) to `utf8`, right?

So, before making the connection in perl i set the environment variable to

```
$ENV{'NLS_LANG'} = ".AL32UTF8"
```

But nothing changes, am i doing it wrong?

When converting the data by hand, in the perl script like this:

```
Encode::from_to($data, 'iso-8859-15', 'utf8');
```

Its works like expected.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: What character(s) are you trying to store in the database?  Are you trying to store characters that are not valid in the ISO-8859-15 character set in a `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, or `CLOB` column?

Comment: Its just "normal" text, numbers and a date. All stored chars are valid  ISO-8859-15 chars.

Comment: are you using DBI or spooling SQL*Plus output and reading into perl? Note that SQL*Plus does not support UTF8, so that will not work.

Comment: I'm using DBI. Btw, what happens when i set the connection directly to utf8? Should that work because it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a perl expert.  But the `NLS_LANG` parameter would normally need to be something like

```
NLS_LANG = GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8
```

not merely `AL32UTF8`.  Is `NLS_LANG` set somewhere else in your environment?  Or is the perl script the only thing that is setting it?

Comment: Hi Justin, the docu says its possible to set the charset only in the NLS_LANG like this: ".AL32UTF8" (the . is necessary). Also valid is something liek this: "_GERMANY.AL32UTF8" or this: "_GERMANY". It is set by the perl script only, before the connection to make sure the right environment is active at that moment.